# Rust STM32F4 HardFault while Initialize RAM

Tags: rust, stm32

**System:**

- Win10
- VS Code
- rustc 1.39.0 (4560ea788 2019-11-04)

and:

```
[dependencies]
cortex-m = "0.6.0"
cortex-m-rt = "0.6.10"
cortex-m-semihosting = "0.3.3"
panic-halt = "0.2.0"
```

**Description**

I followed the steps described in https://rust-embedded.github.io/book/start/hardware.html

I got the following:

```
PS C:\stm32\rustspace\test002> cargo build --example hello
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.05s
PS C:\stm32\rustspace\test002> arm-none-eabi-gdb -q .\target\thumbv7em-none-eabihf\debug\examples\hello
Reading symbols from .\target\thumbv7em-none-eabihf\debug\examples\hello...
(gdb) target remote :3333
Remote debugging using :3333
core::fmt::Formatter::pad () at src/libcore/fmt/mod.rs:1285
1285    src/libcore/fmt/mod.rs: No such file or directory.
(gdb) load
Loading section .vector_table, size 0x400 lma 0x8000000
Loading section .text, size 0x152c lma 0x8000400
Loading section .rodata, size 0x5c0 lma 0x8001930
Start address 0x8001490, load size 7916
Transfer rate: 11 KB/sec, 2638 bytes/write.
(gdb) monitor arm semihosting enable
semihosting is enabled
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8000444: file examples\hello.rs, line 11.
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
Note: automatically using hardware breakpoints for read-only addresses.

Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x0800191e in HardFault_ (ef=0x0) at C:\Users\Klaus Liebler\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cortex-m-rt-0.6.11\src\lib.rs:555
555             atomic::compiler_fence(Ordering::SeqCst);
```

Further debugging revealed, that the Hard Fault happens when executing these lines in lib.rs

```rust
// Initialize RAM
r0::zero_bss(&mut __sbss, &mut __ebss);
r0::init_data(&mut __sdata, &mut __edata, &__sidata);
```

What can I do?

Comment: Don't break on `main`, but `break *0x8000000`, so you will start at the entry point. From there you can step and see where the fault occurs

Comment: @hellow But `0x08000000` is _not_ the start address - it _contains_ the the initial stack pointer! Break at the reset handler. The problem might result from wrong settings in the linker script, whereby `__sbss` and friends receive wrong addresses. Also, if the CCM is initialized, it needs to be enabled first. Please show the linker script and startup code and the output of `disas` and `info reg` and `bt` and `x/16xw $sp` and `x/16xw 0x08000000` during the crash.

Comment: Indeed, this looks like something like using a linker script for a chip variant with a greater amount of RAM or similar broken setup.  The *address of* the reset routine is stored at 0x08000004 - it's the first true vector in the vector table after the initial stack pointer in the zeroeth position.

Comment: Thank you, @Chris Stratton. You gave the right hint. In fact I believed in the "256K RAM" advertisement  for my chip (STM32F429) and was not aware of the fragmented memory map. Changing the line (in file memory.x) `RAM : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 256K` into `RAM : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 192K` solved my problem

Comment: You should post that as an answer so that this can be resolved.  Incidentally the remainder turns out to be core coupled memory at 0x1000 0000